# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,141'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am reading data from csv to perform feature elimination. Here is how data look like

```
shift_id    user_id status  organization_id location_id department_id   open_positions  city    zip role_id specialty_id    latitude    longitude   years_of_experience
0   2   9   S   1   1   19  1   brooklyn    48001.0 2.0 9.0 42.643  -82.583 NaN
1   6   60  S   12  19  20  1   test    68410.0 3.0 7.0 40.608  -95.856 NaN
2   9   61  S   12  19  20  1   new york    48001.0 1.0 7.0 42.643  -82.583 NaN
3   10  60  S   12  19  20  1   test    68410.0 3.0 7.0 40.608  -95.856 NaN
4   21  3   S   1   1   19  1   pune    48001.0 1.0 2.0 46.753  -89.584 0.0
```

Here is my code -

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header = 0)
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header = 1)
target = dataset.location_id
#dataset.head()
svm = LinearSVC()
rfe = RFE(svm, 3)
rfe = rfe.fit(data, target)
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

But I am getting this error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,141'
```

There is not string like this in my database.

There are some empty cell. So I tried to use -

```
result.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Which gave this error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=None.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Any suggestion how to preprocess this data correctly?

Here is link to sample data- https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/6db4f9f9741a16e46fc294b8e2703dc7

Comment: `(float('1,141'.replace(",","."))` should do it

Comment: @user5173426: Actually when I check My data, I dont find `1,141` any where in my data

Comment: Can you show us an output of something like `cat prod_data_for_ML.csv | grep 141` executed in the folder where your file is, assuming you're on Linux?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: Supricingly it is ``141,5,S,14,23,33,1,newton,"48001",3,15,42.643,-82.583,2
"1,141","1,139",A,14,24,77,1,OWINGS MILLS,"21117",8,,39.41,-76.79,
"4,141","1,694",A,16,34,124,1,Redmonds,"98051",1,2,47.33,-121.879,
"5,141","4,584",A,122,179,307,1,Gotham,"02458",1,7,42.35,-71.186,

Comment: When I do direct search on csv file, it does not find it

Comment: Tell us do you want `1,141` to be `1141` or `1.141`?

Comment: @JhonPatric What is your desired output?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: It should be `1141`

Comment: If you intend to feed this dataset to SVM do not forget convert categorical features to numeric via `TfidfVectorizer` or the likes...

Comment: @JhonPatric 
`print(int('1,141'.replace(",","")))` ?

Comment: @user5173426 You need to apply it columnwise...

Comment: @user5173426: But I dont understand how to use this in my code. I am not reading individual parameter like you exampled. If it is seperated by `,` and we read it using panda, should it not manage it ?

Comment: Pls see my answer below for your first error. As far your second error concerned, I highly doubt it comes from `fillna` line. I suggest you double check your code and find the real line of code that produces the second error.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: I really appreciate your answer and comments. And others too. Actually in my data I checked, first column has half of the values in `int` and half were `string`. So `"1,141"` was `1141` actually. No need to replace it. 
What I did it, went to csv file editor and explicitly converted column type to `number` so this issue resolved.

Comment: @JhonPatric, Great that you figured it out. You may mark an answer by clicking on the tick sign beside it, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question contains `result.fillna(0, inplace=True)`.

But since `result` appears nowhere before, it is not clear, what is its value (probably a scalar).

Another weird detail in your code. Look at:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("prod_data_for_ML.csv",header = 0)
data = pd.read_csv("prod_data_for_ML.csv",header = 1)
```

Note that you read twice, from **the same file**, but:

- the first time you read with `header = 0`, so, as the documentation
  states, *column names are inferred from the first line*,
- the second time you read with `header = 1`.

Is this your intention? Or maybe in both calls `header` should be the same?

And one more remark: Reading 2 times from the same file is (in my opinion)
unnecessary. Maybe your code should be like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("prod_data_for_ML.csv",header = 0)
target = data.location_id
```

## Edit

As I undestood from your comments, you want:

- the first table - `dataset` - **with** the first column (`shift_id`),
- the second table - `data` - **without** this column.

Then your code should contain:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header = 0)  # Read the whole source file, reading column names from the starting row
data = dataset.drop(columns='shift_id')       # Copy dropping "shift_id" column
...
```

Note that `header=1` does not "skip" any column, but states only from which source row read column names.
In this case:

- Row No 0 (the starting row, containing actual column names) is
  **skipped**.
- Column names are read from **the next** row (due to `header=1`),
  containing actually the first row of data.
- Only the **remaining** rows are read into rows of the target table.

If you want to "skip" some source columns, call `read_csv` with `usecols`
parameter, but it specifies which columns to **read** (not to skip).

So, assuming that your source file has 14 columns (numbered from 0 to 13),
and you want to omit only the first (number 0), you could write
`usecols=[*range(1, 14)]` (note that the upper limit (14) is **not**
included in the range).

And one more remark concerning your data sample:
The first column is the **index**, without any name.
`shift_id` is the **next** column, so to avoid confusion, you should
put some indentation in the first row.

Note that `City` column is in your header at position **8**, but in data rows
(Brooklyn, test) at position **9**.
So the "title" row (column names) should be indented.

## Edit 2

Look at your comment to the question, written 2019-02-14 12:40:19Z.
It contains a row like this:

```
"1,141","1,139",A,14,24,77,1,OWINGS MILLS,"21117"
```

It shows that first 2 columns (`shift_id` and `user_id`) contain
string representation of a float but with a **comma** instead of a **dot**.

You can cope with this problem using your own converter function, e.g.:

```
def cnvToFloat(x):
    return float(x.replace(',', '.'))
```

and call `read_csv` passing this function in `convertes` parameter, for
such "required" (ill-formatted) columns e.g.:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header = 0, 
    converters={'shift_id': cnvToFloat, 'user_id': cnvToFloat})
```

Comment: The reason why I read twice is; in target I want first column and in another data variable I dont want first column so I started with `header = 1`

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv("prod_data_for_ML.csv",header = 1)
target = data.location_id` will give me error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location_id'`

Comment: `header = 1` means actually "read column names from row 2" (row numeration is from 0). So probably: you skip row 0 (actual column names), read the first **data** row as column names. Then (probably) no column name read from there is `location_id`, so you get the error (you try to refer to a non-exixting column).

Comment: @Can you please update code to avoid this two read and fulfill location_id too

Comment: The "non-existing" string `1,141` may be a result of "glueing together" of two
adjacent columns, the first containing "1", then comes the comma separating
columns and then "141". As the source file is *.csv*, you may perform such check:
Open the file using any text editor. Then look for `1,141` in its content.
If you find something like this, look **very thoroughly** at this row.
Maybe some column contains a comma, causing wrong division of this source row into destination columns.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,141'` is using a `thousands` param in your `pd.read_csv()`:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header = 0, thousands= r",")
dataset.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 14 columns):
shift_id                3 non-null int64
user_id                 3 non-null int64
status                  3 non-null object
organization_id         3 non-null int64
location_id             3 non-null int64
department_id           3 non-null int64
open_positions          3 non-null int64
city                    3 non-null object
zip                     3 non-null int64
role_id                 3 non-null int64
specialty_id            2 non-null float64
latitude                3 non-null float64
longitude               3 non-null float64
years_of_experience     3 non-null object
dtypes: float64(3), int64(8), object(3)
memory usage: 416.0+ bytes
```

Comment: You may also need to declare any values that representing null values using the argument `na_values=...' and give it a list, or those vals may cause pandas to choke. Perhaps also make the conversion to float explicit with `dtype={'some_col':float}`

Answer (score 0):

`1,141` is an invalid float.

To convert it to float, you should first convert it to a valid type, replacing `,` with `.` and then casting it to `float` would work.

```
bad_float = '1,141'

print(float(bad_float.replace(",",".")))
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.141
```

**EDIT:**

As noted by @ShadowRanger, Unless the comma is actually supposed to be a comma for separating digit groupings (to make it more human readable):

```
comm_sep = '1,141'

res = comm_sep.split(",")

print(float(res[0]), float(res[1]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.0 141.0
```

**EDIT 2:**

The issue was resolved by OP as he changed the `column type` to `number` explicitly from the csv file editor.

Comment: Unless the comma is actually supposed to be a comma for separating digit groupings (to make it more human readable), in which case you just get rid of the commas, you don't replace them with periods. The sample data uses periods for the decimal separator after all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Agreed, *if* that is the case, Added an example for that as well.

Comment: You slightly misinterpreted (my fault for not being more explicit), but your misinterpretation of my point is also a possibility. :-) I was suggesting that the number was actually `1141`, with comma inserted every three digits. So a larger number might appear as `12,345,678`, and be intended to mean `12345678`.

Comment: Thanks everyone - But issue is when I check my data it does not contain `1,141` anywhere. So converting to float does not make sense. Or I am going wrong?

Comment: @JhonPatric you just mentioned you want `1,141` to be `1141`: 
`print(int('1,141'.replace(",","")))` ?